# Use of unresolved identifier 'Messaging', 'MessagingDelegate', 'MessagingRemoteMessage'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Yesterday I cleared the Derived data folder enitrely and started facing this error.

I tried :

1. Clearing Derived Data and Clean and rebuild
2. Deleting all pods using `pod deintegrate` and reinstall using `pod install`
3. Deleting the `Podfile.lock` file
4. Run `pod update` to update the pods

My podfile contains these Firebase pods:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

But the error still remains. Anyone faced this error lately.

[image]

Comment: Have you imported the header file in AppDelegate?
import Firebase

Comment: @PratyushPratik Yeah. The green color indicates that it can be located. Even when I `CMD+Control` click, it takes me to the `Messaging` interface. But somehow it still shows me the error

Comment: Build the project to refresh Xcode's ModuleCache

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I did all that. The only fix was to do `import FirebaseMessaging` explicitly. Earlier I was using `import Firebase` only. But now it's crashing saying *The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized*. I am doing that in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but still facing this crash

Comment: @user121095 any update on this?

Comment: @VivekBansal I had to explicitly do `import FirebaseMessaging` instead of the standard `import Firebase`

Answer (score 11):

Simply explicitly import 'FirebaseMessaging' in your project, I had to call it explicitly to make it work.

```
import FirebaseMessaging
```

Comment: Perfect one-liner, You made my day!

Comment: I am glad it helped you. :)

Comment: I love you, save my time! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Open your project, in Project Navigator click on Pods.xcodeproj and in a targets list check if your pod is installed. If it is not then pods are not installed properly or Firebase might removed it because it was deprecated.